# Density function - probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

My question is  - 
If I have this density:

$$f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
A,  & 0 \le x \le 2 \\
B, & 2 < x \le 5 \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

and it is known that $E(x) = 3.05$
I need to find $P(0.05<X≤3|X>0.1)$

So how can I calculate A and B? Do I'm add them together to 3.05? and then do the formula of Bayes theorem?

Comment: What is f? Is it the probability density function?

Comment: I've written your question with MathJax instead of an image. It is helpful to learn it https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5025#5025

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look the informatio you have:

$$\begin{cases}
2A+3B=1 \\ 
A\int_0^2x dx+B\int_2^5x dx=3.05 \\ 
\end{cases}
$$

$$\begin{cases}
2A+3B=1 \\ 
2A+10.5B=3.05 \\ 
\end{cases}
$$

that means:

$$\begin{cases}
A=0.09 \\ 
B=0.273 \\ 
\end{cases}
$$

EDIT: rest of the solution

First of all a drawing:
[image]

This is the graph of your density. As you can check, the total area is correctly 1 (but some decimals)

Your probability states

$$\mathbb{P}[0.05 <X <3|X>0.1]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[0.1 <X <3]}{\mathbb{P}[X>0.1]}=\frac{(2-0.1)\cdot 0.09+(3-2)\cdot 0.273}{(2-0.1)\cdot 0.09+(5-2)\cdot 0.273}\approx 0.448$$

Comment: Thank you! I used Bayes theorem  with $(P(A)*P(B))/P(A)$ and got $0.878$

Comment: Shouldn't that be $10.5$ instead of $12.5$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe :yes sorry it was a calculation error. Just amended. Thanks a lot for you comment :)

Comment: @JustEquvilant : I do not agree, see my edit in previous answer

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your $f_X$ is a probability density function (PDF).

Note that the integral (over the possible range of the data $X$) of any PDF is 1 (since probabilities sum to 1). This is your first condition.

Also, you have a value for the expectation. This is your second condition.

Now, you can find A and B (two unknowns) using the two conditions above.

To find the conditional probability you stated, use Bayes Theorem.